# Questions in proof theory (Definition of an interpretation of one theory in another, Girards Book from '87)

Tags: logic, foundations, proof-theory, meta-math

I am working through the above mentioned book, 'proof theory and logical complexity, volume 1', with some trouble here and there.
I would be glad if someone can help me with some of the exercises, clarify things when I can't work out the sense/meaning or help with the understanding of the proofs.

This is about definition 1.4.5.

I think I basically got this, still I wonder whether there is some 'nicer' reformulation. I find this to be a bit jolty, bulging or clumsy.

Also a few simple examples/applications of this definition (in the language/style of the book) would help me getting the essence of it.

Thanks for your help,

Regards,
Ettore

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

There is the $\text {L}_0$ language of *arithmetic* with function symbols : $s,+,\cdot$ and (binary) relation symbols : $=,<$.

There is the $\text {EA}$ theory of *elementary arithmetic* based on the previous language with suitable axioms.

Then there is the $\text {PRA}$ theory of *primitive recursive arithmetic* with a different language : $\text {L}_{pr}$.

$\text {L}_{pr}$ ahs many function symbols: one for each primitive recursive function, like e.g. the *remainder* of division.

The gist of **Def.1.4.5** is to find a way to "mimick" in a theory $\text T$ based on the language $\text {L}_0$ the functions of $\text {PRA}$.

Due to the fact that $\text {L}_0$ has only the "basic" arithmetical functions : $s,+,\cdot$, to express a $\text {PRA}$ function $f$ means to find a suitable formula $A$ such that :

> $\text T \vdash A(x,y,z) \text { iff } f(x,y)=z$ holds in $\text {PRA}$.

---

A very simple example, is the way to define $<$ in *Peano first-order arithmetic* :

> $n < m \text { iff } \exists k \ (m=n+s(k))$.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that makes sense. When you write that f(x,y)=z holds in PRA, do you mean provable formally in PRA or true under the interpretation for PRA?

Comment: @Ettore - good point; see page 68 : "the interpretations of all axioms of $\text {PRA}$ are theorems of $\text T$." But Girard seems to adopt a "formalist" point of view: thus, being $\text {PRA}$ a *formal theory*, to say that $f(x,y)=z$ holds in it means to say that the "equation" is derivable from $\text {PRA}$ axioms.